# Bash separation of line with newlines instead of spaces

Tags: linux, bash

I did two following commands:

With the first one I listed content of directory and stored it in variable.
Second one shows content of variable.

[image]

Now I decided that I want to separate listing not with spaces but with newlines, I do the following:
[image]

I get a mess. Why?

It's worth to note that when I changed command so, it worked as I wanted:
[image]

Could someone please explain, why 0x20 or 32 ( I tried this number too) is not treated Bash as space in this case?

Comment: Why do you not use `ls -1` ?

Comment: There is something [fundamentally wrong](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs "Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)") here.

Comment: guys, I know about options to ls. I'm just playing with bash.

Comment: I have explained what you looked for in my answer. You need to the basics then you should play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tr` simply doesn't recognize hex but octal. This would work:

```
tr '\040' '\n'
```

And the easier way to show your files is

```
shopt -s nullglob  ## Optional.
printf '%s\n' *
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `tr '\0x20'` is, `tr` is treating all the character sequence as literal characters. And the characters are `0`, `x`, `2`. Note all of theese characters were replaced in the output by `\n`. That's why you have `.t` instead of `txt`. Also `2` didn't appear too.

This is **not** bash, its **`tr`** which is making you unhappy. If you really want to iterate over file names there are better ways to do that.

```
for f in *; do
   # do work with $f. But always use quotes. Like `"$f"`
done
```